# Route static page with vue-router

Tags: web, vue.js, vue-router

I'm fairly new to web development and I was wondering if there was a way to route a static web page with its own stylesheets and javascripts, using `vue-router`.

Let's say I have a directory called *staticWebPage* that contains:

- an `index.html` file
- a *javascripts* directory containing `.js` files
- and a *stylesheets* directory containing `.css` files

Now, I'd like to map `/mystaticwebpage` to this `index.html` file so it displays that particular static web page.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import AComponent from './components/AComponent.vue'
import MyHtmlFile from './references/index.html'

router.map({
   '/acomponent': {
      component: AComponent
   },
   'mystaticwebpage': {
       component: MyHtmlFile
   }
})
```

Of course, this doesn't work as I can only reference Vue components in `router.map`.

Is there a way to route to that `./staticWebPage/index.html` file using all the `.js` and `.css` file contained in the `/staticWebPage` directory?

Comment: Mh, Vue router is a client-side router, so it would probably not result into static pages, by definition.

Comment: Do you think there could be a workaround, not using Vue router? I'd just like to put a static page with the same domain name as the one my Vue app is using

Comment: I think using vue-router is perfectly fine, but that's not a static pages system.

Comment: I don't get it.. then it's not fine for what I want to achieve, right?

Comment: @Randy, I think `preprender-spa-plugin` is what you need. Check this out http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/prerender.html

Answer (score 1):

So for your case you can do something that uses Webpack’s code-splitting feature.

More precisely, what you want is probably async components. So the code (and the css) used in the component definition (including any script you included there) will be loaded only when the corresponding page is accessed.

> In large applications, we may need to divide the app into smaller
> chunks and only load a component from the server when it’s actually
> needed. To make that easier, Vue allows you to define your component
> as a factory function that asynchronously resolves your component
> definition. Vue will only trigger the factory function when the
> component actually needs to be rendered and will cache the result for
> future re-renders.

It can be a bit challenging to setup, so please refer to the [dedicated guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components) in the VueJS doc.

Comment: Note that it does not allow you to load html files, of course. But you can includes any html you want in components template.